# Auto change known Stack Overflow links in the comments

Tags: feature-request

Whenever you post a link to a post or page on Stack Overflow it automatically changes the link to display the title of the page/post. This works in answers and questions, but not in the comments.

[Use amphp/parallel library for non-blocking process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56131739/use-amphp-parallel-library-for-non-blocking-process)

See this post I was trying to post a link to the MCVE, and I have seen comments where it shows up as "Minimal, Complete..." title, but mine did not.

So I was wondering if this is something we could have added just for ease of use.

Comment: Only `https://sitename.tld/questions/id` URLs behave like that. For the MCVE link, use `[mcve]`. See [Add data.SE style “magic links” to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/289905).

Comment: So would siimply put [mcve]

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, this magic link only works on the main site, not on Meta.

Comment: Ahh okay so thats pretty easy to use but there is a lot to remember

Comment: [SE Comment Link Helper](//stackapps.com/q/2378)

Comment: Note that by following links through the SE Comment Link Helper page, we arrive at [a cross-site duplicate of this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394/155739), which was already declined.